# Trying to convert a string into a int using stringstream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stringstream

I'm trying check if a string representation equals given integer. I'm meant to use stringstream for this in a function. I also have an `operator=` for this as well.

I'm a little confused on how to execute these together and if I'm missing something. This is the last bit to an assignment I have, this is just a small snippet of my whole program. I can't find many guides on this, and I sense they all direct me to atoi or atod, which I'm not allowed to use.

```
#ifndef INTEGER
#define INTEGER
using std::string;
class Integer
{
private:
    int intOne;
    string strOne;
public:
    Integer() {
        intOne = 0;
    }
    Integer(int y) {
        intOne = y;
    }
    Integer(string x) {
        strOne = x;
    }
    void equals(string a);  
    Integer &operator=(const string*);
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

In this header I'm not sure what argument I'm to use for the = operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Integer.h"
using namespace std;

Integer &Integer::operator=(const string*)
{
    this->equals(strOne);
    return *this;
}

void Integer::equals(string a)
{
    strOne = a;
    toString(strOne);
}

string Integer::toString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << intOne;
    return ss.str();
}



 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Menu.h"
#include "Integer.h"
#include "Double.h"



int main()
{
    Integer i1;
    i1.equals("33");
    cout << i1;
}
```

Sorry if its a bad question I'm not too familiar with this type of assignment and will take any help I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::to_strig()` that lets you convert from int to a string that represents the same number.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand correctly, you want to overload operator `=`, and that is a bad idea, since `operator=` is used for assignment not for comparison.

The correct operator signature is:

```
ReturnType operator==(const TypeOne first, const TypeSecond second) [const] // if outside of class
ReturnType operator==(const TypeSecond second) [const] // if inside class
```

Since you can't compare string to integer (they are different types), you need to write your comparisment function, since you don't have one i will write one for you:

```
bool is_int_equal_string(std::string str, int i)
{
    std::string tmp;
    tmp << i;
    return tmp.str() == i;
}
```

Last but not least, you need to merge both of those, into one convenient operator:

```
// inside your Integer class
bool operator==(std::string value) const
{
    std::stringstream tmp;
    tmp << intOne;
    return tmp.str() == ref;
}
```

Now you can use this operator, just like any other:

```
Integer foo = 31;
if (foo == "31")
    cout << "Is equal" << endl;
else
    cout << "Is NOT equal" << endl;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use `std::to_string` then it would be the best.

Otherwise, you could create a function to handle the equality between the string and the integer with the use of `std::stringstream`:

Example:

```
bool Integer::equal(const string& str)
{
    stringstream ss(str);
    int str_to_int = 0;
    ss >> str_to_int;

    if (intOne == str_to_int)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Combine this with an `if` statement:

```
int main()
{
    Integer i{100};

    if (i.equal("100"))
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false" << endl;
}
```